# Ilog gantt, stop deselecting pucks on mouse down

Tags: java, gantt-chart, ilog, gant

I am trying to find a solution for stopping deselection on mouse down for ilog gantt chart... there is a method in IlvGanttSelectInteractor called mouseDown which is deselecting the pucks..

I want to deselect on mouse up..

Any suggestions would be great...